# Is there a literary term for the circular nature of a story?

Tags: literary-techniques

Is there a literary term for the circular nature of a story, starting in place *a*, going on to *b* and *c* before returning to complete at *a* again?

Comment: @Rory has a very good point but I couldn't resist talking about the monomyth. :)

Comment: Only vaguely on-topic, but I'm moved to wonder whether there might be a literary/cinematographic term for the device whereby a movie, say, opens with a brief scene which may be utterly incomprehensible due to lack of context at that stage. But which by the end of the movie turns out to be a perfectly rational *final denouement*, and may actually be repeated. In short, an artform that begins where it ends, rather than ends where it began.

Comment: @MrHen - good answer. I hadn't seen it laid out like that. Thanks for the Wikipedia link.

Comment: sorry rory alsop, and all who have answered questions, but not been acknowledged..i dont really know how this sites works.

Comment: Related to [chiasmus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiastic_structure), but not quite the same.

Comment: oh thats good too, prettier, the chiastic structure of the story...would that read right?

Comment: @iminei: it's okay, we all had to start somewhere. In short: on any question of yours, you can select the answer that has helped you most by clicking on [the check mark to the right of it](http://www.imgur.com/OeDf3) (click on this link to see an image). Nobody can *force* you to do that, but it helps us in figuring out which answer you liked most, *and* you get 2 rep points for doing that.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean ending a story where it began, one term for this is *bookending* or employing *[book ends](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BookEnds)* <sup>*[warning: TV Tropes]*</sup> (check examples under the *Literature* tab).

Also, I once had a professor who described poems that do this as "the snake biting its tail"—which I just discovered is an ancient symbol/archetype named [Ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros).

Comment: that is it, book ending, not a beautiful phrase but definitely what i was looking for. thankyou

Comment: @mmyers: What's with the warning? I've seen that on other questions, but I don't get it. Is TV Tropes considered unreliable because of its structure?

Comment: TV Tropes ends up [like this](http://xkcd.com/609/) for a great many people (myself included if I'm not careful). If you're immune, good for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a tad broad but you may be thinking of the "Hero's Journey" or "[monomyth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomyth)". The steps of the journey are:

1. Departure
2. Initiation
3. Return

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomyth) has plenty of details for each step. For instance, the subgroups for Departure are:

1. The Call to Adventure
2. Refusal of the Call
3. Supernatural Aid
4. The Crossing of the First Threshold
5. Belly of The Whale

The term originated with Joseph Campbell's work on myth and examples can be found in plenty of works. Two modern examples are *Star Wars* and *Ender's Game*.

Edit: In response to the clarification, here are a few relevant terms.

- throwback
- callback
- revisiting
- reminiscent

Comment: sorry mr hen but im looking for the word for the linguistic  device of ending a story in the same place it started

Comment: almost like the first and last scene of the film Scandal...where John Hurt was surveying the same street scene, (albeit with subtle differences)

Comment: @iminei: You should add that clarification to the actual question, too. :)